# Что за оператор: '??'

Tags: php

В выражении

```
if ($next['referer'] ?? null) { }
```

Comment: http://php720.com/lesson/19

Comment: Нормальный вопрос, зачем минусуете?

Comment: @u_mulder а вы самостоятельно пробовали набрать этот вопрос в гугле не зная названия оператора?

Comment: Конечно, там подсказка даже выпадает "php оператор два знака вопроса"

Comment: @u_mulder правила Stack Overflow недвусмысленно указывают, что если Google находит подобный ответ на SO, то необходимо закрыть ответ, как дубликат. А если не находит - то ответ **необходимо** добавить. Каким бы "банальным" или "ленивым" вопрос не был.

Answer (score 8):

Это короткая форма (синтаксический сахар) тернарного оператора с isset()

```
$referer = isset($next['referer']) ? $next['referer'] : ''
```

который, в свою очередь, является короткой формой условного оператора

```
if (isset($next['referer'])) {
    $referer = $next['referer'];
} else {
    $referer = null;
}
```

Называется null coalescing operator, или в переводе, [оператор объединения с null](http://php.net/manual/ru/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op). Название это не очень точное, правильнее было бы назвать "оператор выбора из двух вариантов, существующей переменной или дефолтного значения", но это было бы слишком длинно. В любом случае, это мудреное название означает, что РНР выбирает из двух вариантов, "объединяет" их: если переменная есть, то используется её значение, если переменной нет или она равна null - то используется значение, указанное после `??`.

Отдельно следует отметить, что **в приведенном написании** (`if ($next['referer'] ?? null)`) **этот оператор не имеет смысла**, поскольку нам не нужно возвращать никакое значение, а нужно лишь узнать, установлена ли переменная $next['referer']. В этом случае правильнее будет явно вызвать функцию isset():

```
if (isset($next['referer']))
```

это повысит осмысленность и читабельность кода. Поскольку код должен делать только то, что нужно, и в нем не должно быть бессмысленных участков.

Правильное применение данного оператора - это использование возвращаемого значения, например

```
$username = $_GET['user'] ?? 'nobody';
// или
echo $_GET['user'] ?? '';
```

Вся эта история придумана для того, чтобы избежать ошибки "Notice: Undefined variable/index/offset" с наименьшим количеством кода. Но следует при этом помнить, что большинство пользователей РНР не понимают смысла этой ошибки, и считают её досадной помехой, от которой надо избавляться любыми средствами. Разумеется, это не так. Как и любое сообщение об ошибке, это предупреждение сигнализирует программисту о возможных проблемах в коде. И поэтому бездумное подавление этой ошибки путем применения оператора `??` оказывается столь же вредным, как и использование оператора `@`.

Функции isset(), empty() и оператор объединения с null следует применять только в том случае, если заведомо ожидается, что переменной может не быть. Если же переменная должна быть, то этот оператор применять не следует, а вместо этого надо дать РНР сообщить об ошибке. Классический пример неправильного использования - это обработка текстовых полей HTML формы. Все поля HTML формы, за исключением чекбоксов и радиокнопок всегда в обязательном порядке передаются на сервер. То есть, проверять их на существование не нужно. Если возникнет ошибка "Undefined index" - то либо у нас опечатка в имени поля/индексе массива в РНР, либо форма была подделана (с ошибками). В обоих случаях дальнейшая обработка формы будет бессмысленной, а выдача ошибки - единственно правильным сценарием.

Comment: Это не не замена тернарного оператора - это замена `isset for empty`, выражением `??''`, в вашем ответе много воды, тернарный оператор сокращает `if-else`, а тернарный сокращает иногда `?:`

Comment: И кстати о птичках, `isset` никогда не была функцией и называть ее функцией не правильно. Кто-то не читал про данную конструкцию не слова, оказывается.

Answer (score 3):

Это оператор объединения с `null` `??` - Он возвращает первый операнд, если он задан и не равен `NULL`, а в обратном случае возвращает второй операнд:

```
if($next['referer'] ?? '') {
}

if($next['name'] ?? $next['email'] ?? $next['theme'] ?? $next['text'] ?? '') {
}
```

Мы так-же можем это определить в переменных, а дальше проверять как нужно.

```
$name = $next['name'] ?? '';
$email = $next['email'] ?? '';
$theme = $next['theme'] ?? '';
$text = $next['text'] ?? '';
if(!$name) {
    //...
} else if(!$email) {
    //...
} else if(!$theme) {
    //...
} else if(!$text) {
    //...
} else {
    //...
}
```

`??` - данный оператор работает только на `php 7` и выше, в версиях ниже:

```
if(empty($next['submit'])) {
    //переменная пуста
}
if(!empty($next['submit'])) {
    //переменная не пуста
}
```

`isset` работает немного по другому, [советую посмотреть таблицу сравнения типов](http://php.net/manual/ru/types.comparisons.php). На заметку: Поддерживает оператор `and so on`.

```
if(isset($next['name'], $next['email'], $next['theme'], $next['text'])) {
    //...
}
```

`empty` и `isset` разные конструкции языка, но выполняют одинаковую роль, проверку переменной на ее существование, только лишь `empty` проверяет ее более строго, чем `isset` и нет такого прототипа, как имеет `isset - bool isset ( mixed $var [, mixed $... ] )`, где `$...` - и есть `and so on` (и так далее...), а в `empty` такого к сожалению нет.
В php 7 мы также можем определять свои методы и функции:
`func(string ...$var){//...}`, вы задействуете оператор `and so on` (и так далее...) и сможете передавать неограниченное количество аргументов типа `string` или вообще любой тип убрав задаваемый тип переменной `func(...$var)`.

В ранних версиях `php`, также есть тернарный оператор, который заменяет конструкцию `if-else`:

```
$if = true;
$echo = 'Good!';
echo $if ? $echo : 'Empty!';
```

Если вдруг - переменной `$if` не будет существовать или ранее удалится через `unset($if)`, перед выводом через тернарный оператор, будет выведено уведомление (`Notice`) о том, что переменная не определена ранее, тут то и понадобится `isset` или `empty`, чтобы избежать `Notice` уведомлений:

```
$if = true;
$echo = 'Good!';
unset($if);
echo isset($if) ? $echo : 'Empty!';
```

В `php 5.3` появилось сокращение тернарного оператора в виде `?:`:

```
$if = '';
$echo = 'Good!';
echo $if ?: $echo; // Good!
```

Но без проверки через `isset`, `empty` или `??` (`null coalescing`) вы будете ловить `Notice` (уведомления о несуществующих переменных или константах, если вдруг напишите `$next[referer]` без кавычек внутри [`'`referer`'`]).

Comment: Воу-воу "но выполняют одинаковую роль, проверку переменной на ее существование" С чего это? Роли совсем разные. isset - проверяет факт объявления переменной и отличной её от null. empty скормите несуществующую переменную и он скажет, что она пуста. Хотя её вообще не существовало, а ещё empty 0 считает пустотой. Вообще разные роли у этих конструкций.

Comment: я вообще не понял, почему большая часть ответа про троеточие и т..п,  хотя спрашивали про два вопроса.

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev, я имею ввиду, что роль в проверке на существование и `Notice` не появится. Читайте внимательнее.

Comment: @teran, дело в том, что про `...` я добавил к `isset`, а после объяснил с чем это применяется и как работает и чем отличается. Я согласен, что как работают конструкции языка - это другой вопрос и более развернутый, но я добавил в качестве заметки к ответу -  это для того, чтобы ответ был более полным.

Comment: Предупреждение посетителям этого сайта: Практическая ценность данного ответа весьма спорная, поскольку актуальные факты здесь перемешаны с фантазиями автора и полностью неверными утверждениями. Автор имеет весьма смутное представление об операторах РНР, наделяет их несуществующими функциями, а так же выдумывает свои собственные операторы, не существующие в реальности. Функционал описанных в данном ответе операторов следует изучать не по этому посту, а по официальной документации.

Answer (score 2):

Это замена if(isset()) - else. Появилось в PHP 7.

```
// Извлекаем значение $_GET['user'], а если оно не задано,
// то возвращаем 'nobody'
$username = $_GET['user'] ?? 'nobody';
// Это идентично следующему коду:
$username = isset($_GET['user']) ? $_GET['user'] : 'nobody';
```

Подробнее: 
http://php.net/manual/ru/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op